How to set the background color of a whole app?
I'm working on an app that has a custom background color. I'm using the .background modifier on ContentView.
When the app starts up, there's a white / black flash (which might be fixed with a splash screen), but more importantly, there's a white / black background behind sheets.
Is it possible to define that background color? Is it similar to how you can define AccentColor in the Assets?
Notice the white background that appears at the top of the app behind the sheet:

Code:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { isPresented.toggle() }) {
                Text("Show sheet")
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                    .font(.title2)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.brown)
        
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            Text("Notice how a white background appears behind ContentView")
                .font(.title2)
                .padding()
                .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.gray)
        }
    }
}

Background color is also applied to ContentView():
@main
struct BackgroundIssueApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .background(Color.brown)
        }
    }
}


Can you please provide more details about your question? It would be helpful if you could include an image and some code snippets. Thank you.

@helloimbrando Thanks. Added screen recording and code for clarity.

Based on my extensive research, it seems impossible (without going deep into UIKit) to change the background color of your sheets. However, there is a simple workaround:

Create a custom view with the desired background color and remember to apply the .ignoresSafeArea(.all) modifier.

Utilize one of the available libraries to implement a customized bottom sheet for your custom view. (es: danielsaidi/BottomSheet)


It is possible to specify various Detents for your sheet, which can be extremely useful in certain situations.
